# how to solve dereferencing null pointer?

Tags: java, sdk, null, warnings, xml-deserialization

```
byte bytes [] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(element.getElementsByTagName("Bytes").item(0).getTextContent());
Importer imp = null;
fmd = imp.ImportFmd(bytes, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004);
```

I'm getting warning dereferencing null pointer, how can I resolve this warning in ImportFmd method?
I'm using digital persona sdk.

Comment: what is `imp` that is assigned as null. u try to access method `imp.ImportFmd(..)` which us `null.ImportFmd(..)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an instance of the `Importer` class to call the `ImportFmd` method on.

Some Googling turns up that you can get an `Importer` instance this way:

```
UareUGlobal.GetImporter()
```

So your code becomes:

```
byte bytes [] = Base64.getDecoder().decode(element.getElementsByTagName("Bytes").item(0).getTextContent());
Importer imp = UareUGlobal.GetImporter();
fmd = imp.ImportFmd(bytes, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004, Fmd.Format.ANSI_378_2004);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your variable `imp` is null when you access it first: In the second line, you assign null to it, and on the third line, you call the method `ImportFmd` on it.

You need to check the documentation of `Importer` on how to set it up correctly. It could be as simple as

```
Importer imp = new Importer();
```

but OTOH, it probably needs some more work to set it up. The important thing here is that you have to assign a valid value to the `imp` variable, otherwise it is null when you access it first and this will cause a `NullPointerException`.